# syntax error, unexpected '@', expecting ')'

Tags: php, preg-replace

I am making a Content Management System, and when opening the following code I keep getting the same error (using XAMPP):

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '@', expecting ')' in C:\xampp\htdocs\cms\classes\Article.php on line 47

I have already tried replacing '@' whith ')', but it still doesn't work. If I do so, the error becomes:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':' in C:\xampp\htdocs\cms\classes\Article.php on line 47

```
public function __construct( $data=array() ) {
    if ( isset( $data['id'] ) ) $this->id = (int) $data['id'];
    if ( isset( $data['publicationDate'] ) ) $this->publicationDate = (int) $data['publicationDate'];
    if ( isset( $data['title'] ) ) $this->title = preg_replace ( "/[^.,-_'"@?!:$ a-zA-Z0-9()]/", "", $data['title'] );
    if ( isset( $data['summary'] ) ) $this->summary = preg_replace ( "/[^.,-_'"@?!:$ a-zA-Z0-9()]/", "", $data['summary'] );
    if ( isset( $data['content'] ) ) $this->content = $data['content'];
  }
```

I want it to run without any issues.

Comment: You need to escape the double quotes within your regex. See the highlighting in your code here? It shows where it's breaking

Comment: `"/[^.,-_'\"@?!:$ a-zA-Z0-9()]/"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should escape double quotes like this: \", just add the slash before.

The problem on lines 7 and 8.
This code works for me.

```
    public function __construct( $data=array() ) {
    if ( isset( $data['id'] ) ) $this->id = (int) $data['id'];
    if ( isset( $data['publicationDate'] ) ) $this->publicationDate = (int) $data['publicationDate'];
    if ( isset( $data['title'] ) ) $this->title = preg_replace ( "/[^.,-_'\"@?!:$ a-zA-Z0-9()]/", "", $data['title'] );
    if ( isset( $data['summary'] ) ) $this->summary = preg_replace ( "/[^.,-_'\"@?!:$ a-zA-Z0-9()]/", "", $data['summary'] );
    if ( isset( $data['content'] ) ) $this->content = $data['content'];
  }
```